# Erro ao instalar Netbeans 8.2 no Windows 10

Tags: java, netbeans

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000744b6adf, pid=9300, tid=0x0000000000002364
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b14) (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000019836000):  JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9060, stack(0x000000001ad30000,0x000000001ae30000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x000000001ae2ee00, RCX=0x0000000000000000, RDX=0x000000000129a290
RSP=0x000000001ae2eda8, RBP=0x000000001ae2ef90, RSI=0x00000000000000ce, RDI=0x00000000198361f8
R8 =0x000000000129a290, R9 =0x0000000000000000, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x000000001ae2c460
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000001ae2efb0, R14=0x000000001ae2ef78, R15=0x0000000019836000
RIP=0x00000000744b6adf, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001ae2eda8)
0x000000001ae2eda8:   0000000073a09e16 0000000000000000
0x000000001ae2edb8:   00000000198361f8 00000000000000ce
0x000000001ae2edc8:   000000000129a290 00000000198361f8
0x000000001ae2edd8:   0000000073a0a7d9 000000000129a290
0x000000001ae2ede8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001ae2edf8:   0000000073da0093 0000000000000000
0x000000001ae2ee08:   0000000000000000 0000000019836000
0x000000001ae2ee18:   00000000ffffffff 00000000ffffffff
0x000000001ae2ee28:   0000000073e7c379 0000000019836000
0x000000001ae2ee38:   0000000019908440 0000000000000000
0x000000001ae2ee48:   0000000000000534 00000000db262000
0x000000001ae2ee58:   0000000000000000 000000001ae2f0c0
0x000000001ae2ee68:   000000000329cb74 0000000019836000
0x000000001ae2ee78:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001ae2ee88:   0074007300610050 0065006400000005
0x000000001ae2ee98:   0000000019836000 000000001ae2f0c0 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000744b6adf)
0x00000000744b6abf:   99 03 00 cc 33 c0 48 8b 5c 24 40 48 8b 74 24 48
0x00000000744b6acf:   48 83 c4 30 5f c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 48 8b c1
0x00000000744b6adf:   0f b7 10 48 83 c0 02 66 85 d2 75 f4 48 2b c1 48
0x00000000744b6aef:   d1 f8 48 ff c8 c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 45 33 c0 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000001ae2ee00 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000019836000
RCX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000000129a290 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001ae2eda8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000019836000
RBP=0x000000001ae2ef90 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000019836000
RSI=0x00000000000000ce is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000000198361f8 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000000129a290 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x000000001ae2c460 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000019836000
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000001ae2efb0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000019836000
R14=0x000000001ae2ef78 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x0000000019836000
R15=0x0000000019836000 is a thread


Stack: [0x000000001ad30000,0x000000001ae30000],  sp=0x000000001ae2eda8,  free space=1019k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [msvcr100.dll+0x36adf]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 1193  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.getDisplayNameOf(JJI)Ljava/lang/String; (0 bytes) @ 0x00000000032b7309 [0x00000000032b72c0+0x49]
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$1600(JJI)Ljava/lang/String;+4
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$13.call()Ljava/lang/String;+15
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$13.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+42
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+95
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run()V+7
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x0000000019836000 JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9060, stack(0x000000001ad30000,0x000000001ae30000)]
  0x00000000199b5800 JavaThread "Image Fetcher 0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9540, stack(0x000000001ac30000,0x000000001ad30000)]
  0x00000000199c1800 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=5252, stack(0x000000001a460000,0x000000001a560000)]
  0x0000000019936000 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5244, stack(0x000000001a330000,0x000000001a430000)]
  0x0000000019a06000 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=5220, stack(0x000000001a230000,0x000000001a330000)]
  0x0000000019a05800 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9860, stack(0x000000001a130000,0x000000001a230000)]
  0x0000000018cc8800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9400, stack(0x00000000190a0000,0x00000000191a0000)]
  0x0000000017356800 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9396, stack(0x0000000018ba0000,0x0000000018ca0000)]
  0x0000000017351800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9392, stack(0x0000000018aa0000,0x0000000018ba0000)]
  0x000000001734d000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9388, stack(0x00000000189a0000,0x0000000018aa0000)]
  0x000000001734a800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9384, stack(0x00000000188a0000,0x00000000189a0000)]
  0x0000000017349000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9380, stack(0x00000000187a0000,0x00000000188a0000)]
  0x000000001733a800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9376, stack(0x00000000185a0000,0x00000000186a0000)]
  0x0000000002e8e000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9372, stack(0x00000000184a0000,0x00000000185a0000)]
  0x0000000002da0800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_blocked, id=9348, stack(0x0000000002ca0000,0x0000000002da0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000017318000 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000183a0000,0x00000000184a0000] [id=9368]
  0x0000000018ccb800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00000000191a0000,0x00000000192a0000] [id=9404]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 34816K, used 27228K [0x00000000d9980000, 0x00000000dc000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 30208K, 90% used [0x00000000d9980000,0x00000000db4172e8,0x00000000db700000)
  from space 4608K, 0% used [0x00000000dbb80000,0x00000000dbb80000,0x00000000dc000000)
  to   space 4608K, 0% used [0x00000000db700000,0x00000000db700000,0x00000000dbb80000)
 ParOldGen       total 79360K, used 0K [0x000000008cc00000, 0x0000000091980000, 0x00000000d9980000)
  object space 79360K, 0% used [0x000000008cc00000,0x000000008cc00000,0x0000000091980000)
 Metaspace       used 16436K, capacity 16632K, committed 16896K, reserved 1064960K
  class space    used 2124K, capacity 2199K, committed 2304K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000012260000,0x0000000012600000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000011dfa000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x00000000743fa6c0
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000012c70000, 0x0000000014940000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000014940000, 0x0000000016610000)

Polling page: 0x00000000011c0000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=4234Kb max_used=4234Kb free=241525Kb
 bounds [0x0000000002ea0000, 0x00000000032d0000, 0x0000000011ea0000]
 total_blobs=1722 nmethods=1209 adapters=427
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 11.463 Thread 0x0000000017356800 1209   !   3       java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue::offer (130 bytes)
Event: 11.465 Thread 0x0000000017356800 nmethod 1209 0x00000000032c1750 code [0x00000000032c1a00, 0x00000000032c2fc8]
Event: 11.465 Thread 0x0000000017356800 1210       3       java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue::dequeue (32 bytes)
Event: 11.465 Thread 0x0000000017356800 nmethod 1210 0x00000000032c3b90 code [0x00000000032c3ce0, 0x00000000032c3e70]
Event: 11.465 Thread 0x0000000017356800 1211       1       javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI::getFileChooser (5 bytes)
Event: 11.466 Thread 0x0000000017356800 nmethod 1211 0x00000000032c3f50 code [0x00000000032c40a0, 0x00000000032c41b0]
Event: 11.466 Thread 0x0000000017356800 1212       1       java.awt.MediaEntry::getID (5 bytes)
Event: 11.466 Thread 0x0000000017356800 nmethod 1212 0x00000000032c4210 code [0x00000000032c4360, 0x00000000032c4470]
Event: 11.466 Thread 0x0000000017356800 1201       1       java.awt.image.Raster::getHeight (5 bytes)
Event: 11.466 Thread 0x0000000017356800 nmethod 1201 0x00000000032c44d0 code [0x00000000032c4620, 0x00000000032c4730]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (10 events):
Event: 9.025 Thread 0x0000000002da0800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000000000317ed78 method=java.io.WinNTFileSystem.prefixLength(Ljava/lang/String;)I @ 42
Event: 9.075 Thread 0x0000000002da0800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003050050 method=java.lang.String.startsWith(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z @ 25
Event: 9.895 Thread 0x00000000199c1800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x00000000031842a4 method=java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(I)Ljava/lang/AbstractStringBuilder; @ 16
Event: 9.895 Thread 0x00000000199c1800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003175318 method=java.lang.Integer.getChars(II[C)V @ 7
Event: 9.895 Thread 0x00000000199c1800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003182d14 method=java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(I)Ljava/lang/AbstractStringBuilder; @ 16
Event: 10.257 Thread 0x00000000199c1800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000307d9dc method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 10.257 Thread 0x00000000199c1800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000307d9dc method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 10.257 Thread 0x00000000199c1800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000307d9dc method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 10.257 Thread 0x00000000199c1800 Uncommon trap: reason=class_check action=maybe_recompile pc=0x000000000307d9dc method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 11.292 Thread 0x00000000199c1800 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x0000000003273ad4 method=java.util.Hashtable.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; @ 48

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.047 Thread 0x0000000002da0800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BII)Ljava/lang/Class; name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d9987c78) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\
Event: 0.047 Thread 0x0000000002da0800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchMethodError': Method sun.misc.Unsafe.prefetchRead(Ljava/lang/Object;J)V name or signature does not match> (0x00000000d9987f60) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims
Event: 0.789 Thread 0x0000000002da0800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d9ae6830) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.789 Thread 0x0000000002da0800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d9ae6c28) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.790 Thread 0x0000000002da0800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d9aeac40) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 0.790 Thread 0x0000000002da0800 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x00000000d9aeb038) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1386]
Event: 8.740 Thread 0x0000000002da0800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000dade58f0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]
Event: 8.833 Thread 0x0000000002da0800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000daeb11b0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 8.837 Thread 0x0000000002da0800 Exception <a 'java/lang/NoSuchFieldError': method resolution failed> (0x00000000daebe8a0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\methodHandles.cpp, line 1146]
Event: 9.025 Thread 0x0000000002da0800 Exception <a 'java/io/FileNotFoundException'> (0x00000000db03dcc0) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u111\7883\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 709]

Events (10 events):
Event: 11.224 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$18 done
Event: 11.224 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$ColumnComparator$1
Event: 11.224 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$ColumnComparator$1 done
Event: 11.225 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$11
Event: 11.225 loading class sun/awt/shell/Win32ShellFolder2$11 done
Event: 11.292 Thread 0x00000000199c1800 Uncommon trap: trap_request=0xffffff65 fr.pc=0x0000000003273ad4
Event: 11.292 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 11.292 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 11.292 Thread 0x00000000199c1800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000003273ad4 sp=0x000000001a55d020
Event: 11.292 Thread 0x00000000199c1800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000002ee582a sp=0x000000001a55cfc8 mode 2


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff682430000 - 0x00007ff682467000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe
0x00007ff9dda20000 - 0x00007ff9ddbfb000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ff9ce2d0000 - 0x00007ff9ce303000     C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\x64\aswhooka.dll
0x00007ff9dd3a0000 - 0x00007ff9dd44e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ff9dad30000 - 0x00007ff9daf79000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ff9d8590000 - 0x00007ff9d860e000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
0x00007ff9db650000 - 0x00007ff9db6f1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ff9dd070000 - 0x00007ff9dd10d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ff9dce40000 - 0x00007ff9dce99000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ff9dd110000 - 0x00007ff9dd235000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ff9dd250000 - 0x00007ff9dd39a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ff9da870000 - 0x00007ff9da88e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ff9dd040000 - 0x00007ff9dd067000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ff9d9f40000 - 0x00007ff9da0c9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ff9da7d0000 - 0x00007ff9da86a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ff9dab20000 - 0x00007ff9dac16000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ff9ccac0000 - 0x00007ff9ccd27000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.15063.0_none_108e4f62dfe5d999\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ff9daf80000 - 0x00007ff9db279000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ff9daab0000 - 0x00007ff9dab1a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ff9dd9f0000 - 0x00007ff9dda1d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x0000000074480000 - 0x0000000074552000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000073be0000 - 0x000000007447a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ff9db7e0000 - 0x00007ff9db7e8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ff9ce830000 - 0x00007ff9ce839000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ff9dcd60000 - 0x00007ff9dcdcc000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ff9cd730000 - 0x00007ff9cd753000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ff9ccd30000 - 0x00007ff9ccd3a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ff9cd700000 - 0x00007ff9cd72b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ff9da890000 - 0x00007ff9da8d9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x0000000073bd0000 - 0x0000000073bdf000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000073ba0000 - 0x0000000073bc9000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java.dll
0x0000000073b80000 - 0x0000000073b96000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ff9db920000 - 0x00007ff9dcd57000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ff9db870000 - 0x00007ff9db91a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007ff9da0d0000 - 0x00007ff9da7c2000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ff9db700000 - 0x00007ff9db751000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ff9d9e90000 - 0x00007ff9d9ea1000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ff9d9eb0000 - 0x00007ff9d9efc000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ff9d9f20000 - 0x00007ff9d9f35000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
0x00007ff9d98e0000 - 0x00007ff9d98f7000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x00007ff9d9360000 - 0x00007ff9d9394000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x00007ff9d9cc0000 - 0x00007ff9d9ce5000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
0x00007ff9d9dc0000 - 0x00007ff9d9de9000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ff9d9900000 - 0x00007ff9d990b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x0000000073b60000 - 0x0000000073b7a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\net.dll
0x00007ff9d9740000 - 0x00007ff9d979c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007ff9d94e0000 - 0x00007ff9d9517000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x00007ff9dd240000 - 0x00007ff9dd248000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll
0x00007ff9d22e0000 - 0x00007ff9d22f6000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x00007ff9d2680000 - 0x00007ff9d269a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x0000000073b40000 - 0x0000000073b51000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000001400000 - 0x0000000001407000     C:\Users\Suporte\AppData\Local\Temp\nbi-3556799220888281451.tmp
0x00007ff9db280000 - 0x00007ff9db3c5000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
0x00000000739a0000 - 0x0000000073b38000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\awt.dll
0x00007ff9dd930000 - 0x00007ff9dd9ef000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007ff9d86b0000 - 0x00007ff9d8745000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007ff9db3d0000 - 0x00007ff9db536000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ff9d4c00000 - 0x00007ff9d4c2a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll
0x0000000073950000 - 0x0000000073997000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x00007ff9ceac0000 - 0x00007ff9ceb66000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.15063.0_none_43a14f3b47f396e6\comctl32.dll
0x00007ff9dd890000 - 0x00007ff9dd92e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll
0x00007ff9d4240000 - 0x00007ff9d43d6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\propsys.dll
0x00007ff9c0790000 - 0x00007ff9c08b7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NetworkExplorer.dll
0x00007ff9cacc0000 - 0x00007ff9cb1f1000     C:\Windows\System32\OneCoreUAPCommonProxyStub.dll
0x00007ff9cc100000 - 0x00007ff9cc2ac000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x00007ff9bebb0000 - 0x00007ff9bec07000     C:\Windows\System32\thumbcache.dll
0x00007ff9d7120000 - 0x00007ff9d7196000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\policymanager.dll
0x00007ff9d7030000 - 0x00007ff9d70bf000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msvcp110_win.dll
0x00007ff9b2360000 - 0x00007ff9b24e9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\d3d9.dll
0x00007ff9c7d60000 - 0x00007ff9c7ec4000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\aticfx64.dll
0x00007ff9b3380000 - 0x00007ff9b33a1000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\atiu9p64.dll
0x00007ff9b1b00000 - 0x00007ff9b2359000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\atiumd64.dll
0x00000000730c0000 - 0x0000000073948000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\atiumd6a.dll
0x0000000073070000 - 0x00000000730b2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\t2k.dll
0x00007ff9ccd90000 - 0x00007ff9ccdab000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x00007ff9c0b40000 - 0x00007ff9c0b4b000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\drprov.dll
0x00007ff9d9980000 - 0x00007ff9d99d5000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WINSTA.dll
0x00007ff9b8420000 - 0x00007ff9b8436000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ntlanman.dll
0x00007ff9b8400000 - 0x00007ff9b8420000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\davclnt.dll
0x00007ff9c0a70000 - 0x00007ff9c0a7c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\DAVHLPR.dll
0x00007ff9d3ac0000 - 0x00007ff9d3ad6000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wkscli.dll
0x00007ff9c9af0000 - 0x00007ff9c9b02000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cscapi.dll
0x00007ff9d9520000 - 0x00007ff9d952d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\netutils.dll
0x00007ff9b82e0000 - 0x00007ff9b832a000     C:\Windows\System32\dlnashext.dll
0x00007ff9b8090000 - 0x00007ff9b80fd000     C:\Windows\System32\PlayToDevice.dll
0x00007ff9c9d30000 - 0x00007ff9c9d4e000     C:\Windows\System32\DevDispItemProvider.dll
0x00007ff9d3600000 - 0x00007ff9d3667000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MMDevApi.dll
0x00007ff9d8860000 - 0x00007ff9d8888000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00007ff9b8100000 - 0x00007ff9b82df000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\wpdshext.dll
0x00007ff9cd760000 - 0x00007ff9cd8f5000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.15063.0_none_9055be80f37df5c1\gdiplus.dll
0x00007ff9b8ce0000 - 0x00007ff9b8d7c000     C:\Windows\System32\PortableDeviceApi.dll
0x00007ff9dd450000 - 0x00007ff9dd88b000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x00007ff9dacd0000 - 0x00007ff9dad26000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WINTRUST.dll
0x00007ff9d9f00000 - 0x00007ff9d9f11000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSASN1.dll
0x00007ff9da8e0000 - 0x00007ff9daaa9000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll
0x00007ff9d18a0000 - 0x00007ff9d18d1000     C:\Windows\System32\PortableDeviceTypes.dll
0x00007ff9bc2e0000 - 0x00007ff9bc316000     C:\Windows\System32\EhStorShell.dll
0x00007ff9c0760000 - 0x00007ff9c0785000     C:\Windows\System32\EhStorAPI.dll
0x00007ff9d6600000 - 0x00007ff9d6613000     C:\Windows\System32\WTSAPI32.dll
0x00007ff9c0b60000 - 0x00007ff9c0b70000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LINKINFO.dll
0x00007ff9cde70000 - 0x00007ff9cde7c000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Secur32.dll
0x00007ff9d9d90000 - 0x00007ff9d9dc0000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SSPICLI.DLL
0x00007ff9d4840000 - 0x00007ff9d4858000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\samcli.dll
0x00007ff9d46d0000 - 0x00007ff9d46f3000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SAMLIB.dll
0x00007ff9d3b80000 - 0x00007ff9d3d29000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Suporte\AppData\Local\Temp\ -Dnetbeans.default_userdir_root=C:\Users\Suporte\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans -Dnetbeans.default_cachedir_root=C:\Users\Suporte\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache 
java_command: org.netbeans.installer.Installer
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\Suporte\AppData\Local\Temp\\NBI62957.tmp\bundle.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Suporte\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
USERNAME=Suporte
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 21 Model 16 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 15063 (10.0.15063.296)

CPU:total 4 (4 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 21 model 16 stepping 1, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, clmul, mmxext, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, sse4a, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv, bmi1

Memory: 4k page, physical 7546252k(5464972k free), swap 10167692k(7887336k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_111-b14), built on Sep 22 2016 19:24:05 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)

time: Wed May 10 12:16:34 2017
elapsed time: 11 seconds (0d 0h 0m 11s)
```

Comment: Este erro esta acontecendo apos a ultima atualização do windows 10, parece ser problema de permissão, poi quando me logo como administrador funciona normalmente e sem erros, para instalar abrir projetos e diretórios, e com o usuário administrador não abre projetos trava e da esse erro.

Answer (score 1):

Bom fiz uma pesquisa no fórum da netbeans.org, e o que causa este problema e pasta God Mode'Modo Deus', que geralmente fica na are de trabalho. Solução apague ela ou coloque em outra unidade e teste, aqui deu certo. esta funcionando perfeitamente agora, testei novamente coloquei a pasta novamente na área de trabalho e ocasionou o mesmo erro citado do colega.

sou novo aqui, então, peço compreensão e tentei ajudar enquanto fazia testes e pesquisas ate encontrar uma resposta.

Estou colocando o link do fórum, espero que esteja fazendo certo, se não peço que ajude a corrigir.

seguem link.

https://forums.netbeans.org/post-174943.html

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, Rudineli!

Comment: caraca .. era isso mesmo aff.. fala serio.. obrigado galera